# Laravel use non composer package

Tags: laravel, include, composer-php, package, autoload

How can I use this non composer package to my controller?
https://github.com/lelag/otphp

I've tried

```
use OTPHP;

$totp = new \OTPHP\TOTP($secret);
```

and I get

> Class 'OTPHP\TOTP' not found

Answer (score 0):

You will need to require the file.

```
require_once('/path/to/otphp.php');
```

Or if you want to use composer.json, look into using [classmaps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap)

Comment: I did like this  require_once('..\vendor\otphp-master\lib\otphp.php'); and it worked.